# Convert this PHP function to get server variables to VB .Net

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am having trouble getting server variables remotely in VB .Net I need to basically mimic this PHP Function.

```
function showvar($string)
{
 if(isset($_SERVER[$string]))
 {
  echo "$string: ".rawurldecode($_SERVER[$string])."\r\n";
 }
}

/*normal vars*/
showvar("HTTP_ACCEPT");
showvar("HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING");
showvar("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE");
showvar("HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET");
showvar("HTTP_HOST");
showvar("HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE");
showvar("HTTP_COOKIE");
showvar("HTTP_UA_CPU");
showvar("HTTP_REFERER");

/*important vars*/
showvar("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
showvar("REMOTE_ADDR");
showvar("REMOTE_HOST");
showvar("HTTP_CONNECTION");
showvar("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
showvar("HTTP_FORWARDED");
showvar("HTTP_VIA");
showvar("KEEP_ALIVE");  
showvar("HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS");
showvar("MAX_FORWARDS");
showvar("HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL");
showvar("HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION"); 
showvar("HTTP_X_BLUECOAT_VIA");
showvar("HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR");
showvar("HTTP_PROXY___________");
showvar("HTTP_PROXY____");
showvar("HTTP_X_FWD_IP_ADDR");
showvar("HTTP_X_HOST");
showvar("HTTP_X_REFERER");
showvar("HTTP_X_SERVER_HOSTNAME");
showvar("PROXY_HOST");
showvar("PROXY_PORT");
showvar("PROXY_REQUEST");
showvar("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
showvar("HTTP_PRAGMA");
```

Can anybody get me pointed in the right direction? Atleast show me how to return one variable. Thanks I have searched everywhere

Comment: Please note I am trying to create a proxyjudge and do not want to have to make a call to a remote server to do so. Is this possible?

Comment: I would like to call proxyJudge(ProxyServer As String) and have it return server variables for the input

Comment: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=5615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Request.ServerVariables(VariableName)`

Example `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")`

Comment: Shoban, that does not work. The Request class is not available in a desktop application. Any other ideas?

Comment: Deskop Application?? Then You will have write a web service and then use this service in your application.